# VCL TListView and EditCaption()

Tags: c++builder, vcl, tlistview

In C++Builder, I've got a `TListView` with some items.

Whenever someone enters a numeric value, it should be applied to the caption of the currently selected `TListItem` in the ListView:

```
void __fastcall TFormMain::ListViewKeyDown(TObject *Sender, WORD &Key,
  TShiftState Shift)
{
    if ( Key >= '0' && Key <= '9' )
    {
        if ( !ListView->IsEditing() )
        {
            ListView->Selected->EditCaption();
        }
    }
}
```

This code works "somehow": Entering a numeric value puts the `TListView` into editing mode. Then I have to re-enter the number to apply it to the `TListItem`'s caption.

Isn't there a way to do `EditCaption()` and apply the number just in one single step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't there a way to do EditCaption() and apply the number just in one single step?

You would have to manually forward the typed digit to the ListView's editor after invoking it, eg:

```
void __fastcall TFormMain::ListViewKeyDown(TObject *Sender, WORD &Key, TShiftState Shift)
{
    if ( (Key >= '0') && (Key <= '9') )
    {
        TListItem *Item = ListView->Selected;
        if ( (Item) && (!ListView->IsEditing()) )
        {
            Item->EditCaption();

            HWND hWnd = ListView_GetEditControl(ListView->Handle);

            TCHAR str[2] = {TCHAR(Key), 0};
            SetWindowText(hWnd, str);
        }
    }
}
```